# complex query about combining data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Recently I had the following request. There are two tables.

```
-- lots of items
declare @items table(id varchar(10), pieces integer)
-- boxes
declare @boxes table(num varchar(10), capacity integer)



insert @items(id, pieces)
select 'l1', 5
union all select 'l2', 12
union all select 'l3', 8

insert @boxes(num, capacity)
select 'o1',2
union all select 'o2', 8
union all select 'o3', 2
union all select 'o4', 5
union all select 'o5', 9
union all select 'o6', 5


-- list all pairs of items-boxes. So that item will be put in what order
-- example: o1-l1, o2-l1, o2-l2, o3-l2, ...
```

Please let me explain it imperative way:
There are two tables. One with items another with boxes. We need to put all items into boxes the following way:

We take first item l1 and first box o1. Item l1 has 5 pieces and box o1  capacity is 2. We can only put maximum 2 pieces into the box o1. So we create first row:

```
o1-l1
```

We have filled the box o1. moving to the next box o2. It has the capacity of 8 and we have item l1 which has 3 pieces left. Putting the left pieces of l1 into the box o2 and so we create the second record:

```
o2-l1
```

We have put all the pieces of the item l1 into the boxes. Moving to the next item l2. It has the 12 pieces. And we have 5 capacity left in box o2 . So we are putting 5 pieces of l2 into o2 and creating the next record:

```
o2-l2
```

Then we are taking the next box in order and creating the following record:

```
o3-l2
```

And this way we are generating the rows till we "put" all item pieces into the boxes.
The resulting query should be something like:

```
o1-l1
o2-l1
o2-l2
o3-l2
...
```

It could be solved imperative way in T-SQL with the CURSOR and stuff, which is not good performance-wise. Is there any SQL query that could generate the desired output?

Comment: Hi. Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hi, SQL Server 2012

Comment: This falls under the category of so-called "bucket filling" problems. It is actually relatively simple to solve using recursive SQL. If I get a chance later (and the question is not already answered by then), I will draft the code and post it. Also, just for clarity, what is the overall quantity of items to be dealt with per query execution? Thousands or tens of millions?

Comment: Hi Steve, 10 to 1000

Comment: Just one problem here - There is no **first** item and there is no **first** box, since you have no ordering column. Database tables are unsorted sets, meaning that *first, last, 3rd from the top etc'* simply can't be applied to them. Only when you specify an `order by` clause your recordset is ordered.

Comment: @IlyaSh, the answer you added to your question looks like it's correct, not taking into account the different table and column names from your table variable definitions. You should create a new Answer for this Question with the working query, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Ilya Sh, I couldn't quite verify if your own answer to your question was correct. But here is my approach.

Originally I thought this could be solved with a recursive query, but that's where all the boxes are equal in size and guaranteed to be bigger than the items, and the items are indivisible but vary in size (so that the only decision in relation to each item is whether it can be packed in the current box, or has to go in the next box).

In this case, we have groups of items (i.e. a row specifying an item type and a quantity) in which the items are equal in size but the groups are divisible, and each item group may therefore be spread over a number of boxes, and each box may contain parts of a number of itemgroups, in a many-to-many relationship between boxes and itemgroups.

My thinking is that each box, according to its capacity, has a number of individual "slots" (i.e. a volume of space) that can receive individual items.

The way I've approached the solution is to employ a "numbers table" to expand the quantities of each box/item group into individual box-slots and individual items - one row per box-slot and one row per item. On my machine I have a table called zx_numbers - but I've included code below that, for illustrative purposes, eliminates the dependency on this table.

Once we have normalised the data in this way - by expanding boxes into their individual slots, and expanding the item groups and summary quantities into individual items - each box slot and item in the entire batch is numbered sequentially, and then the two are simply joined on that sequence number.

I've used an `FULL OUTER JOIN` to preserve unmatched slots/items. This gives us a very general and adaptable solution to the problem, which we can then process further in a variety of ways to get the specific data we want (in this case, just a summary of box-itemgroup combinations).

The way I've written the query currently, boxes with unfilled space (or itemgroups that leave a remainder after all boxes have been fully filled) are left in the results, and placed at the end, but these can be filtered if not required.

```
WITH 
item_groups(item_group_id, group_qty) AS 
(
    select 'l1', 5
    union all select 'l2', 12
    union all select 'l3', 8
    --union all select 'l4', 8
)

,boxes(box_id, capacity) AS 
(
    select 'o1',2
    union all select 'o2', 8
    union all select 'o3', 2
    union all select 'o4', 5
    union all select 'o5', 9
    union all select 'o6', 5
)

,zx_numbers(zx_number) AS
(
    --SELECT * FROM dbo.zx_numbers

    --I have a dedicated numbers table on my machine, but I've substituted a 
    --manual sequence generator for the purposes of a self-contained demonstration
    SELECT
        (ones.n) + (10 * tens.n) + (100 * hundreds.n) AS zx_number

    FROM --range 0 to 999
         (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS ones(n)
        ,(VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS tens(n)
        ,(VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS hundreds(n)
)

,items AS
(
    SELECT 
        item_groups.*
        ,zx_number AS group_item_number
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_group_id, zx_number) AS batch_item_number

    FROM
        item_groups

    INNER JOIN
        zx_numbers
        ON (zx_number BETWEEN 1 AND item_groups.group_qty)
)

,box_slots AS
(
    SELECT 
        boxes.*
        ,zx_number AS box_slot_number
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY box_id, zx_number) AS batch_slot_number

    FROM
        boxes

    INNER JOIN
        zx_numbers
        ON (zx_number BETWEEN 1 AND boxes.capacity)
)

,box_item_matches AS
(
    SELECT
        COALESCE(bxsl.batch_slot_number, itms.batch_item_number) AS slot_number

        ,bxsl.box_id
        ,bxsl.capacity
        ,bxsl.box_slot_number

        ,itms.item_group_id
        ,itms.group_qty
        ,itms.group_item_number

    FROM
        box_slots AS bxsl

    FULL OUTER JOIN
        items AS itms
        ON (bxsl.batch_slot_number = itms.batch_item_number)
)

--SELECT * FROM box_item_matches

SELECT 
    box_id
    ,item_group_id

FROM 
    box_item_matches 

GROUP BY
    box_id, item_group_id

ORDER BY 
    IIF(box_id IS NULL OR item_group_id IS NULL, 1, 0) --i.e. NULLS LAST
    ,box_id
    ,item_group_id
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, I'll try to review it when I get to my sql environment.